# Thick slow recorded sound using android recorder

Tags: android, recorder

I'm developing an android application that records sound using Mediarecorder class
The following is a part from my code:

```
  public void start() throws IOException {
    String state = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if(!state.equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))  {
        throw new IOException("SD Card is not mounted.  It is " + state + ".");
    }

    // make sure the directory we plan to store the recording in exists
    File directory = new File(path).getParentFile();
    if (!directory.exists() && !directory.mkdirs()) {
      throw new IOException("Path to file could not be created.");
    }
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.DEFAULT);
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
recorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(16);
recorder.setAudioSamplingRate(44100);
try {
    recorder.setOutputFile(path);
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
recorder.prepare();
recorder.start();


}
```

when the recorder stops , i played it using mediaplayer class but the result sound is very thick and slow .. what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

As per the MediaRecorder [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html#setAudioSamplingRate%28int%29) the sampling rate for AMRNB is 8kHZ and you are setting this to a different value. I suspect this as the issue.

Can you comment these lines and check if that works for you:

```
//recorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(16); 
//recorder.setAudioSamplingRate(44100);
```

Comment: no I tried to comment these and tried it on real device .. but the same problem

Comment: What is the device you are using?